# System.Text.Json: Handling Infinity values

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization, system.text.json

From what I can tell, this is the appropriate way to handle double "Infinity" values when using NewtonsoftJson, to avoid those values when serializing.

```
x.SerializerSettings.FloatFormatHandling = FloatFormatHandling.DefaultValue;
```

What is the corresponding way to do this when using System.Text.Json?

Answer (score 7):

Without a custom converter you cannot instruct System.Text.Json to write a `0`, but - for the record - `NaN` and the infinities can be handled with `JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals`.

From [JsonNumberHandling Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonnumberhandling?view=net-6.0):

> The "NaN", "Infinity", and "-Infinity" String tokens can be read as floating-point constants, and the Single and Double values for these constants will be written as their corresponding JSON string representations.

```
using System.Text.Json;

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions {
        NumberHandling = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals
    };

Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Double.NaN, options));
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Double.NegativeInfinity, options));
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Double.PositiveInfinity, options));


Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<double>("\"NaN\"", options));
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<double>("\"-Infinity\"", options));
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<double>("\"Infinity\"", options));
```

prints

```
"NaN"
"-Infinity"
"Infinity"
NaN
-∞
∞
```

Comment: How can I use this to convert a float value in a JSON response like 1800.0 to and int property?

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using a custom converter.

In startup.cs

```
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DoubleInfinityConverter())
        );
```

The converter

```
internal class DoubleInfinityConverter : JsonConverter<double>
{
    public override double Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => reader.GetDouble();

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, double value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (double.IsNaN(value) || double.IsInfinity(value))
        {
            writer.WriteStringValue(default(double).ToString());
            return;
        }
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution like this,

it is reference the answer from Jeremy

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Imrc.CommonLib.Components.Common
{
    class DoubleExtConverter : JsonConverter<double>
    {
        public override double Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
            {
                // some editor is okay, but it has error on my computer
                //return Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetString());

                string text = reader.GetString();
                if (string.Equals("NaN", text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return double.NaN;
                }
                else if (string.Equals("-Infinity", text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return double.NegativeInfinity;
                }
                else if (string.Equals("Infinity", text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return double.PositiveInfinity;
                }
                else
                {
                    return double.NaN;
                }
            }

            return reader.GetDouble();
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, double value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (double.IsNaN(value))
            {
                // "NaN":"NaN"
                writer.WriteStringValue("NaN");
                return;
            }
            else if (double.IsNegativeInfinity(value))
            {
                // "NegativeInfinity":"-Infinity"
                writer.WriteStringValue("-Infinity");
                return;
            }
            else if (double.IsPositiveInfinity(value))
            {
                // "PositiveInfinity":"Infinity"
                writer.WriteStringValue("Infinity");
                return;
            }

            //writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
            writer.WriteNumberValue(value);
        }
    }
}
```

And the result

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
        //options.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals;
        options.Converters.Add(new DoubleExtConverter());
        
        var test = new MyTest();
        //test.Num = 20;
        
        string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(test, options);
        Console.WriteLine("JSON: " + json);
        
        var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyTest>(json, options);
        Console.WriteLine("NaN: " + obj.NaN.ToString() + ", double.IsNaN: " + double.IsNaN(obj.NaN));
        Console.WriteLine("NegativeInfinity: " + obj.NegativeInfinity.ToString() + ", double.NegativeInfinity: " + double.IsNegativeInfinity(obj.NegativeInfinity));
        Console.WriteLine("PositiveInfinity: " + obj.PositiveInfinity.ToString() + ", double.PositiveInfinity: " + double.IsPositiveInfinity(obj.PositiveInfinity));
    }
    
    public class MyTest
    {
        public double NaN {get;set;} = double.NaN;
        public double NegativeInfinity {get;set;} = double.NegativeInfinity;
        public double PositiveInfinity {get;set;} = double.PositiveInfinity;
    }
}
```

JSON: {"NaN":"NaN","NegativeInfinity":"-Infinity","PositiveInfinity":"Infinity"}

NaN: NaN, double.IsNaN: True

NegativeInfinity: -Infinity, double.NegativeInfinity: True

PositiveInfinity: Infinity, double.PositiveInfinity: True

Answer (score 0):

If you are using with .net core WebAPI, global serialization has to be done at service level.

e.g.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options => {
    options.SerializerOptions.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals;
});
```

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/responses?view=aspnetcore-8.0#configure-json-serialization-options